# Show box on textbox focus, wrapping the textbox

Tags: jquery, css

Actually it's a lot easier to show you what I want to achieve instead of trying to explain.

State 1:
 [image]

The field Responsibles hos no focus. Pretty simple.

State 2:
[image]

The field Responsibles got focus. A div shows up around the textbox and the text.

It's no problem showing the gray box and position it. The problem is to have the textbox show up inside the box, but still maintain it's current position.

When the textbox is being positioned absolute (tried z-index), the content is being messed up ofcourse.

I'm using jQuery.

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to give the textbox an absolute position. Just give it position: relative and set the zIndex so it comes on top of the gray box. If it has position: static (default) zIndex won't work.

Comment: Actually I haven't thought of this. Will try it out as soon as I can!

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [jQuery Tools Expose](http://jquerytools.org/documentation/toolbox/expose.html)?

---

Here is some code using Expose with mouseover... I also posted a sample at this [pastebin](http://pastebin.me/c68d6e56a5596bcb56def583b4156c77)

```
$(function() {
 $("#test").hover(
  function() {
   $(this).expose({api: true}).load()
  }, function() {
   $(this).expose().close();
 });
});
```

---

Edit: Sorry, here is the code for focus & blur:

```
$(function() {
 $("#test")
  .focus(function() {
   $(this).expose({api: true}).load();
  })
  .blur(function() {
   $(this).expose().close();
  });
});
```

---

Edit #3: Just because I have OCD and can't leave things hanging LOL... I worked out a script that does what you want without using Expose (posted at [this pastebin](http://pastebin.me/a7c70df9da47948565e617ac1c0ca548) as well). You can add a fade in and fade out if you want.

CSS

```
input, select { width: 200px; }
#expose {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #444;
 z-index: 99;
}
.focused {
 position: relative;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 100;
}
label.focused {
 color: #ddd;
}
```

HTML (I tried to mimic your image)

```
<fieldset><legend>Fields</legend>
<label for="frespon">Responsibilites:</label><br/>
<input type="text" id="frespon" class="expose" /><br/>
<br/>

<label for="fprojectid">ProjectID:</label><br/>
<select id="fprojectid" class="expose">
 <option value='-'>-</option>
</select><br/>
<br/>

<label for="fstatusid">StatusID:</label><br/>
<select id="fstatusid" class="expose">
 <option value='-'>-</option>
</select><br/>
<br/>

<label for="ftypeid">TypeID:</label><br/>
<select id="ftypeid" class="expose">
 <option value='-'>-</option>
</select><br/>
<br/>

<label for="ftitle">Title:</label><br/>
<input type="text" id="ftitle" class="expose" /><br/>
</fieldset>
```

Scripting

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.expose').focus(function(){
  $('<div></div>')
   .attr('id','expose')
   .appendTo('body');
  $(this).addClass('focused')
   .parent().find('label[for="' + this.id + '"]').addClass('focused');
 })
 $('.expose').blur(function(){
  $('.expose').removeClass('focused')
   .parent().find('label[for="' + this.id + '"]').removeClass('focused');
  $('#expose').remove();
 })
})
```

Comment: Yeah, I know about jQuery Tools and use it for some other stuff. Actually, in the exampled you sent, if the gradient background of the fields showed up only on focus (like it's changing color), it was exactually what I was looking for!

Comment: Opps, I posted an example above using hover, but you should be able to change it to work with focus & blur

Comment: The "problem" is. I don't wanna use the expose effect. The only thing I want to do is to show a div around the textbox on focus. The textbox should lay on top of the div, but the div should be on top of everything else on the site.

Comment: This wasn't the solution to my problem, but I ended up using the effect. It looks so nice! ;)

Comment: Ok then, I posted a solution above :P... LOL sorry, I've been on a "use this plugin" kick lately. I guess I should just answer the question ;)